# Kubectl how to wait for operator package manifest to be created

Tags: openshift, kubectl

How do I wait in using oc command for an operator package manifest to be available?

I am trying this

```
❯ oc wait --for=condition=ready packagemanifest/example-manifest -n openshift-marketplace
Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
```

This is failing because there is no ready state under spec field of package manifest

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur when the server is configured in a way that does not allow you to perform a specific action for a particular URL.

**Check below possible solutions :**

1)Kubectl resolves are driven by discovery. Please check you may have created two resources with conflicting names one of which is not listable.

2)Check that your Application Default Credentials are configured for a different user than your credentials.

3)Also make sure that your Application Credentials environment variable isn't pointing somewhere unexpected.